# Capturing string before a specific text using Regular Expression

Tags: regex

I have a string 'LKHI8700' and I want to extract three characters before '8700'. 
ForExample in LKHI8700 I would like to extract 'KHI8700'. The length of the string and code will be different thats why I cannot use forward extraction.

Comment: which language ? what have you tried ?

Comment: so 8700 is not static.. thus you better give us 2-3 examples to make understand how the regex should shape

Comment: What do you mean by "he length of the string and code will be different"? Can you show what you mean by adding more examples of how you want to match?

Comment: Examples :
LKHI8700 -> would like to match 3 characters before 8700
LLKHI0784 ->  would like to match 3 characters before 0784

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what about `.*(?=\w{3}\d{4})`

this get any characters before your code and you can replace with each(empty)

- .* - any charackters
- (?= - where after that...
- \w{3} - word characters with length 3
- \d{4} - any digit with length 4

so, if you want your code have upper characters you can change `\w` with `[A-Z]`

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/QTV5V1/1)

also, if you want get just code use : `(\w{3}\d{4})`

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/QTV5V1/3/)

Answer (score 0):

For your given example with only uppercase characters, you might use [`[A-Z]{3}(?=\d{4})`](https://regex101.com/r/gxY3Yx/4)

**This will match**

- Match 3 uppercase characters `[A-Z]{3}` 
  *(or `[A-Za-z]` for upper and lowercase characters)*
- A positive lookahead which asserts that what follows are 4 digits `(?=\d{4})`

Or to extract the three characters before the 4 digits, you could capture them in a group:

[`([A-Z]{3})\d{4}`](https://regex101.com/r/gxY3Yx/3)